# How to write into existing excel file using JExcel

Tags: java, excel, api

Hi I am new with this JExcel API and I want to write into existing excel sheet and want to save the changes in that file. I don't have an idea about how to do it in JExcel?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference in

1. http://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jexcel/docs/JExcel-PGuide.html
2. http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading the documentations?

I've used JExcel and it's an easy framework.

try this one http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html

Tö get you a start change this your excel file, after that you just need to browse the file with JExcel it's pretty easy.

```
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("myfile.xls"));
```

Comment: this will open workbook in read mode only but I want to open in write mode without createWorkbook method is there any other methods available?